# AutoCAD displays `question mark` instead of tab character when using AutoLISP

Tags: text, autocad, autolisp

Software: AutoCAD 2012 (Japanese language)

System: MS Windows 7 (Japanese language)

I have made a .LSP file which defines a new function "C:MAKEATABLE".

I am trying to print a string which contains a tab character, using AutoLISP. But that character shows up as a question mark (?).

If I manually try to edit it (by double-clicking it, or using DDEDIT, or by TEXTEDIT ) it automatically gets converted to the tab character, which I require.

I don`t know which character encoding is being used (if that is causing a problem). 
The font being used is "txt.shx".

**Things I have tried:**

- Used (chr 9)  in concatenation with the rest of the string => still shows up as a question mark
- tried to print the two parts of string (on either side of the tab) separately => not good, since I need that text as a single object
- tried using "DDEDIT" function in the code => It requires the user to press enter at its every invocation, so not good.

  - I tried simulatinging the enter key using " " , "" , ";" , (terpri). Nothing works, it still prompts the user to select another object.
- tried using "TEXTEDIT" function in the code => doesn`t do anything; says that," MAKEATABLE Unknown command "MAKEATABLE". Press F1 for help."
- ran the same code on my English language PC and English version of AutoCAD 2012 => same problem if i use any of the .SHX fonts; but works fine if I use the other fonts like "Arial"

I might have missed a thing or two, so please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a different approach:

Isn't your problem that you are trying to create a "SingleLine text" object in AutoCAD. These do not support TABs. You could try to use the "Multline Text" object instead.

Cheers,
Alain

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I achieved the desired output by changing the style to monospace.